# Open interval in countable Union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a set $I=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} R_n$ where each $R_n$ is a closed set. Then $I$ is a countable Union of closed sets. Can we assert that $ I$ doesn't contain any non-empty open intervals?

Comment: No; let $R_n=[-n,n]$.  Then open interval $(-1,1)\subset I$

Comment: If I let each $R_n$ be a closed interval of positive length, then every $R_n$ contains non-empty open intervals, so certaintly $I$ contains a lot of them. More interesting would be to consider the case where none of the $R_n$ contains a nonempty open interval.

Comment: How can I use this result to show that the set of irrational numbers cannot be written as the countable Union of closed sets?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "contained".  If $R_1 = [0,1]$ then $(0,1) \subset R_1 \subset \cup R_n$ so if by "contained" you mean has a subset then obviously not.  If by contained you mean the class of $\{R_n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ the union of which is $I$ contains no open intervals then yes but that's usually stated as $\{R_n\}$ is a *cover* of $I$ and as a cover $\{R-n\}$ contains no open intervals; not that $I$ contains none.  But that's trivial.  I'm not sure of any legitimate definition of "contain" where we can say this.

Comment: "How can I use this result to show that the set of irrational numbers cannot be written as the countable Union of closed sets?"  All closed intervals contain an open interval and the set of irrationals contains no open intervals.  So if the irrationals could be so written none of the $R_i$ contain any closed intervals.....

Comment: If each $R_n$ has empty interior then we are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your first interval is $[0, 1]$. Then the union contains $(0, 1)$.

For global considerations, suppose the $n$th set is $[1/n, 1 - 1/n]$. Then then union exactly is the interval $(0, 1)$, which is open.